# Zero divisors in an algebra with two generators

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $k$ be a field, and $R = k\langle x,y \mid x^2 = 0\rangle$. The generators $x$ and $y$ are not supposed to commute with each other. Is the only case where nonzero elements  $a, b \in R$ satisfy $ab=0$ when $a\in Rx$ and $b\in xR$?

Comment: Not a research question. Better ask this on MSE. As a hint: it is easy to write down a basis for your space. Using this, the problem boils down to easy linear algebra.

Comment: @J. De Ro This is kind of funny, because one of the top researchers in the field asked me this question (after giving up on this problem himself). Ok, R has an obvious k-base. And now, how do you use linear algebra to solve the problem?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466687/zero-divisors-in-an-algebra-with-two-generators#comment1211215_466687), write $a = a_x + a_x'$ and $b = {}_xb + {}_xb'$ according to the obvious basis, then multiply and see what happens.

Comment: @LSpice I see an obvious basis $(1,t,x,t^2,tx,xt,t^3,t^2x,txt,xt^2,xtx,t^4,t^3x,t^2xt,txt^2,xt^3,txtx,xt^2x,xtxt,t^5,t^4x,t^3xt,t^2xt^2,txt^3,xt^4,t^2xtx,txt^2x,xt^3x,txtxt,xt^2xt,xtxt^2,xtxtx,\dots)$. I assume your decomposition of $a$ (resp. $b$) separates words according to their last (resp. first) letter. What next?

Comment: @YCor, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1211359), let's call these basis elements terms, and measure the length of a term obviously.  Unless the shortest terms in $a$ and $b$ occur only in $a_x$ and ${}_xb$, we may discard all but the shortest terms in $a$ and $b$.  Then the terms that occur when we expand $a_x\cdot{}_x b'$, $a_x'\cdot{}_x b$, and $a_x'\cdot{}_x b'$ are distinct, hence linearly independent.  I'm pretty sure a similar trick, with more bookkeeping, works in the other cases, too, but won't cram it into a comment.

Comment: @YCor I am glad to see that I am not the only one struggling with this problem (besides the (quite famous) person A who told me about the problem, and another person B who told A about it)!

Comment: @LSpice What you have written is pretty obvious. Similarly we may assume that the longest terms in $a$ and $b$ occur only in $a_x$ and $_xb$.

Comment: @LSpice it's sort of not easy to decipher sentences full of "obvious". I see 3 "obvious" ways to define the degree of a monomial: degree in $t$, in $x$, and total degree (sum of the two preceding ones), and sort of guess you mean the latter. Then I'm somewhat stuck with the notation $a_x$, ${}_xb$ you don't define. I now have in mind a proof anyway but would  hope to write it in an answer rather than in 2-3 comments.

Comment: @YCor, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1211423), I agree, but a comment is as long as it is, and it didn't seem worth making multiple comments. The length I meant was the total degree, though I'm sure there are other ways of making it work. You correctly [deduced](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1211359) the meaning of $a_x$ and ${}_xb$ already. I am not sure what to say about your writing an answer; right now neither of us can, because the question is closed, but, once it's opened, I didn't mean to say anything against your answering, only to respond to your comment.

Comment: I have cast the final vote to re-open, so that people can give the proof that is apparently obvious. (I can't help wondering if those who voted to close also think it is obvious that when k is a field and G is a torsion-free group then kG has no non-trivial zero divisors.)

Comment: It seems that the question can be closed again in view of Example 9.3 in the paper *Victor Camillo and Pace P. Nielsen, McCoy rings and zero-divisors, J. Pure Appl. Algebra 212 (2008), no. 3, 599–615*.

Comment: @Ralle You could post this reference as an answer and flag it for the moderators to make it CW

Comment: @Ralle No, don't close the question again. If there's a simple argument given there, you can reproduce it in an answer.

Comment: @YemonChoi no need of moderators to make an **answer** CW

Comment: There is no need to make an answer CW just because it’s posted by the author of the original question. If it’s a genuine answer to a genuine question, and apparently took some effort to find out, you should get proper credit for it.

Comment: The fact that the question is answered in the reference I posted was noticed by the aforementioned person B (who then told A about it, who then told me about it). So I don't deserve any credit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is answered positively in Example 9.3 in the paper *Victor Camillo and Pace P. Nielsen, McCoy rings and zero-divisors, J. Pure Appl. Algebra 212 (2008), no. 3, 599–615*. [DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jpaa.2007.06.010)